# Debug disabled with DDMS on Android

Tags: android-studio, ddms

I am using Android Studio 1.3 with DDMS on Linux 64-bit.  For some reason, when I try to debug with DDMS by selecting my app in the process list and clicking the "bug" in the tool menu, it shows debugging as disabled (grayed out).  However, if I close DDMS and just use Android Studio for debugging, then everything works fine.  Note that I've installed the debug version of my app so I should be able to connect to it.

Is there a way to use DDMS and be able to debug my app at the same time?  I've tried attaching with Android Studio and loading up DDMS but it seems I can only have one ADB session at a time.  Therefore, I must close DDMs before I can debug my app.

Comment: why do you want to use DDMS, Android studio isn't enough ?

Comment: I would like to see heap/memory allocation while I am debugging. Also, I need to be able to send SMS and calls to the emulator.  DDMS offers both functionality.